# How to mention current working directory in Batch File

Tags: batch-file

I want to change the command :

```
copy "D:\Folder\File.txt" "C:\Folder\File.txt"
```

to :

```
copy "%current path%\File.txt" "C:\Folder\File.txt"
```

Is there any way to type like this?

Comment: A filename with no path always reside in the current directory: `copy "File.txt" "C:\Folder\File.txt"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
copy "%cd%\some.file" "c:\there\some.file"
```

or

```
copy "%~dp0some.file" "c:\there\some.file"
```

they are different - `%cd%` is the current executable directory and `%~dp0`  is where the bat file is in case the SHIFT command is not called.Also `%~dp0` cannot be used from the command line as there is no script file.

Answer (score 1):

Try `copy ".\File.txt" "C:\Folder\File.txt"`

Comment: @foxidrive - It's not me if this is what are you asking :-D . Simpler than my proposal...

Comment: @npocmaka Not at all, I don't think you would do that.  Somebody who didn't test it has downvoted that.